# How to replace square bracket and between that get string with color?

Tags: android

Here Example : "some [string] with [the data i want] inside [ashish]"

i want to get string with blue color that are between "["blue colored"]" and replace [ (opening) (closing)] to just space. like facebook tagging  statement.

Comment: you just want to replace "["  and "]" characters with space?

Comment: that is easy .. i want replacement as well as get string between "[" and "]" with blue color.
so i my example i want 
some "blue part <string>" with "blue part <the data i want>" inside "blue part<ashish>

Answer (score 0):

Try following method:

```
    private SpannableString makeBluish(String text)
{
    String temp = text;
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\[([\\sa-zA-Z]+)\\]");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
    while (matcher.find())
    {
        temp = temp.replace(matcher.group(0), (matcher.group(1)));
    }

    SpannableString linkedString = new SpannableString(temp);
    matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
    while (matcher.find())
    {

        final String token = matcher.group(1);

        int index = temp.indexOf(token);

        linkedString.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLUE), index, index + token.length(), SpannableString.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
    }
    return linkedString;
}
```

And

```
textString.setText(makeBluish("some [string] with [the data i want] inside [ashish]"));
```

here `textString` is a TextView.

Comment: Thnq for answer . this is not working for me. so i get my answer by 

http://notepad.cc/bluis

Comment: This is a working code, I have checked it. may be some issue on implementation side. You have solved you problem so doesn't matter, leave it.