# how to change text color and font using Spannablestring

Tags: android

I am beginner in Android application development, so please don't make it as a duplicate question.

My question is that how to change text color and font using spanablestring class.

for example: I am (beginner) in (Android) application (development).

1) how to change above three words font and color.

2) And how to change all words those are between rounded braces if I have many words.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I change the color of a part of a TextView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4032676/how-can-i-change-the-color-of-a-part-of-a-textview)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the color like shown below:

```
Spannable wordtoSpan = new SpannableString("I am (beginner) in (Android) application (development).");        

wordtoSpan.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLUE), 15, 30, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```

For more information on how to change the color look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3282940/set-color-of-textview-span-in-android).

To change the words in the brackets look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31673874/how-to-replace-square-bracket-and-between-that-get-string-with-color).

Comment: Example :("I am (beginner) in (Android) application {development}")
i want change color of "development" what i do?
mean above case was only about single brace but now two brace.
please help me sir.

Comment: @Naeem ask a new question explaining your problem with more details please.

Comment: I just posted. please check.